# Picking specific route/path to destination address

Tags: linux, networking, routes, router, iptables

[image: Sample network]

I want my PC to access/communicate to SERVER-PC thru routerA -> routerB -> ISP-> routerD route not routeC.

- Is it possible?
- How should I do it?
- Should I have access/control over routerD?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: IP was originally designed from DoD funding to automatically reroute traffic in the event of a disaster, e.g. nuclear war. Routing is dynamic, and each packet is routed without regard to any other packets, even those of the same flow that may have come before. A host is in the worst position to determine the best path packets should take.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.

Once you submit a packet to a router/gateway in your local network, the rest of the path is beyond your control. Initially, IPv4 "featured" source-routing but this isn't supported any more.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible with BGP only.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself, however it should be possible assuming ISP has load balancer. What you can do is, generate different type packets with different ports, pkt type etc(figure out what all the fields used for hash calculation). traceroute the packets, figure out which type( with what hash value of packet) go through router D. try to generate packets with same hash value so that ISP load balancer routes the with same hash value packet through same path.

At the end of the day, If you can figure out hashing algorithm used, you should be able make sure your packets go through router D by making sure that your packets have same hash value. All this can be done without having control over the router D.

If you have access to router D it is very easy, Router D can just announce that it has shortest path to Server PC then all the packets will go through the router D.

Comment: Some ISPs actually look for traceroute and reroute the packets to prevent you from casually discovering their internal networks. There are various methods to detect traceroute, but it is common to look for small TTL values because that is how traceroute functions.

Comment: This had been carried out at my university as a research project to understand structure of internet. if one performs traceroute using TCP packets probability of firewalls detecting the traceroute packet is nearly zero.

Comment: I'm not talking about firewalls. I'm talking about ISP equipment that looks for packets with small TTL values and reroutes those packets. You would have no way to know if that happens, and it does happen all the time. The traceroute packets end up taking a different route than normal traffic.

Comment: reroutes means? if ISP reroutes, we will figure out another way to destination, I have done traceroute, i know it is not trustable completely however after enough number of measurements you will get a path to the destination. user has to look at time taken between the hop. If you are interested i can give you the link to papers published.

Comment: I have seen such papers, and many ISPs are laughing at them. The ISPs have ways of figuring out such things that you simply do not know. The transport protocol (TCP, UDP, etc.) actually plays no part in routing packets on the public Internet, and you are fooling yourself if you think it does. You may be able to get past an end-site firewall using TCP, but that really has nothing to do with Internet routing. That also doesn't even touch on the problem that the public Internet is always in flux, with routes changing as connections are made or removed between ISPs.

Comment: Also, how do you determine the path for packets that are sent through a tunnel? To the encapsulated packet, the tunnel is a single hop, while the outer packet may be routed through dozens of routers, about which the traceroute packet knows nothing. It looks to traceroute like the tunnel endpoints are directly connected, but they probably are not.